# Display message after countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have currently created a countdown timer using javascript. I want to display a message right after the countdown finishes. So, how do I display that text message if the countdown finishes?

```js
$(function(){
 
 var note = $('#note'),
  ts = new Date(2012, 0, 1),
  newYear = true;
 
 if((new Date()) > ts){
  // The new year is here! Count towards something else.
  // Notice the *1000 at the end - time must be in milliseconds
  ts = (new Date()).getTime() + 24*60*60*1000;
  newYear = false;
 }
  
 $('#countdown').countdown({
  timestamp : ts,
  callback : function(days, hours, minutes, seconds){
   
   var message = "";
   
   message += hours + " jam ";
   message += minutes + " minit" + " dan ";
   message += seconds + " saat" + " lagi!";
   
  
   note.html(message);
  }
 });
 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        
        <!-- Our CSS stylesheet file -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/countdown/jquery.countdown.css" />
        
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    
    <body>
<div id="continer">
  <p><span id="timer"></span></p>
</div>  
        <center><img class="title" src="title.svg"></center>
        <img class="icon1" src="icon1.svg">
        <img class="icon2" src="icon2.svg">

  <div id="countdown"></div>

  <p id="note"></p>

        <!-- JavaScript includes -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/countdown/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Below is the code that I used

Comment: try [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_countdown)

Comment: http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html#events

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use setInterval, clearInterval and use a counter to keep track of seconds passed

```
function myFunction() {
     var seconds = 0;
     var finiteNumber = 300; // any number which can be calculated
     var interval = setInterval(function(){
         seconds++;
         if(seconds === finiteNumber) {
            console.log(seconds);
            clearInterval(interval )
          }
    }, 1000);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use setTimeout as it will automatically stop on one successful execution.

```
function myFunction() {
var myTimeInSeconds = 600;
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(seconds);
    alert('Success');
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Success Message!";
}, myTimeInSeconds);
}
```